# Derivatives of Polygamma Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, special-functions, digamma-function, polygamma

I would like to know if there's a quicker way to verify:

$$\partial_z^{n-1}\psi(tz)t^n = \partial_z^n\ln[\Gamma(tz)], \,\,\\ n \in \mathbb{N}^+, t \in \mathbb{C}_+\tag{1}\label{1}$$

That's true for $t=1$. But what about a complex $t$?

For complex $t$, $(1)$ holds for $n=1,2,3$. These computations were done by hand. I searched any information that would help me on DLMF (https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.15), but nothing relevant was found.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition,
$$\psi(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \ln \Gamma(x).$$

Therefore,
$$\dfrac{\partial^{n}}{\partial z^n}\ln\Gamma(t z)
 = \dfrac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}}\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\ln\Gamma(t z)\right) 
= \dfrac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}}\Big(t\, \psi(t z)\Big)= t^{\color{brown}{\mathbf{1}}}\dfrac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}} \psi(t z)$$

(see also [WA calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E3%2Fdz%5E3%20ln%20Gamma%28%20t%20z%29%20%2F%20d%5E2%2Fdz%5E2%20polygamma%280%2C%20t%20z%29) for $n=3$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not so sure if I understood how you achieved such result. May I ask you to detail it more?

Comment: @Mr.N Thank you for the comment. Detalized.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thanks for the details. So it matches to "my" hypothesis, right? May we apply the chain rule and then: $t \partial_z^{n-1}[ \psi(zt) ] = t^n \psi^{(n-1)}(zt)$ ?

Comment: @Mr.N This variant looks [quite correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28d%5E3%2Fdz%5E3+ln+Gamma%28+t+z%29+%29%2F+polygamma%282%2C+t+z%29).